# Getting the output from the console into localhost:8080

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

How to get correctly the output from the console into the browser https://localhost:8080/ . I worked on some other small spring mvc restful web services project and i was smoothly able to the date on localhost:8080/ I just wonder why i cat with this project.

Here is some of the output :

```
Customer: Customer [userId=1, forename=homer, lastname=simpson, email=hsimpson@springfield.com, mobileNumber=0781 123 456, password=marge, orders=[
 Order [orderId=0 total Order cost: 86.9, orderItems=[
 OrderItem [item=Item [title=Dummies Guide to Dummies, publisher=Red Penguin, price=10.45, yearPublished=2014] Book [author=Man Equine], count=2 total cost=20.9], 
 OrderItem [item=Item [title=Release the hounds, publisher=Red Penguin, price=22.0, yearPublished=2014] Book [author=Rufus Ruff], count=3 total cost=66.0]]],
```

Either

```
   Whitelabel Error Page
   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
   Wed Mar 22 23:20:49 EET 2017
   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
   No message available
```

Or

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080.
```

[Download my code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9H2qsKiTIenbHpPcjBrTXVoek0)

Here is the BackendServiceImpl class:

```
public class BackendServiceImpl implements BackendService {

    private static final String[] bookTitles = new String[]{"Dummies Guide to Dummies","Release the hounds","How to be happy"};
    private static final float[] bookPrice = new float[]{10.45f, 22.00f, 5.50f};
    private static final String[] bookAuthors = new String[]{"Man Equine","Rufus Ruff","Oona Appy"};
    private static final Random random = new Random();


    private static final List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    static {
         for (int index = 0; index < bookTitles.length; index++) {
                bookList.add(createBook(index));             
         }
    }

    private Map<Integer, Customer> customers = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Customer>();


    private Map<Integer, Order> orders = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Order>();

    private AtomicInteger customerIdCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    private AtomicInteger orderIdCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    public BackendServiceImpl() {
        initialiseCustomers();
    }

    private static Book createBook(int index) {

        final Book book = new Book(bookTitles[index], "Red Penguin", bookPrice[index], 2014, bookAuthors[index]);

        return book;
    }

    private OrderItem createOrderItem() {

        int index = random.nextInt(bookTitles.length);

        final Book book = bookList.get(index);

        final OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(book);

        final int quantity = random.nextInt(3);
        for(int c = 0; c < quantity; c++) {
            orderItem.incrementQuantity();          
        }

        return orderItem;
    }

    private Order createOrder() {

        final Order order = new Order();

        final int numberOrderItems = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

        Set<OrderItem> set = new HashSet<OrderItem>();

        int count = set.size();
        while(count < numberOrderItems) {
            set.add(createOrderItem());
            count = set.size();
        }

        order.setOrderItems(new ArrayList<OrderItem>(set));

        final int index = orderIdCounter.getAndIncrement();

        order.setOrderId(index);

        orders.put(index, order);

        return order;
    }

    private List<Order> createCustomerOrders() {

        final int numberOrders = random.nextInt(3) + 1;     

        final List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

        for (int index = 0; index < numberOrders; index++) {
            orders.add(createOrder());
        }
        return orders;
    }

    private int addCustomer(final String firstName, final String lastName, final String email, final String mobileNumber, final String password) {
        final Customer customer   = new Customer(firstName, lastName, email, mobileNumber, password);
        int id = customerIdCounter.incrementAndGet();
        customer.setUserId(id);

        final List<Order> customerOrders = createCustomerOrders();


        for(Order order : customerOrders) {
            customer.addOrder(order);
        }

        customers.put(id, customer);

        return id;

    }

    private void initialiseCustomers() {
        addCustomer("homer", "simpson", "hsimpson@springfield.com", "0781 123 456", "marge");

        addCustomer("ned", "flanders", "nflanders@springfield.com", "0781 777 888", "maude");

        addCustomer("monty", "burns", "mburns@springfield.com", "0781 $$$ $$$", "release the hounds");
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {       
        List<Customer> customersList = new ArrayList<Customer>(customers.values());
        return customersList;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        return customers.get(customerId);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Order> getCustomerOrders(int customerId) {
        final Customer customer = customers.get(customerId);
        return customer.getOrders();
    }

    @Override
    public Order getOrder(int orderId) {
        return orders.get(orderId);
    }

    public static void main (final String[] args) {
        final BackendService service = new BackendServiceImpl();

        final Customer customer = service.getCustomer(1);

        System.out.println("Customer: " + customer);
    }

    @Override
    public int createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return addCustomer(customer.getForename(), customer.getLastname(), customer.getEmail(), customer.getMobileNumber(), customer.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCustomer(int id) {        
        customers.remove(id);       
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi Be-.-Happy, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry to be telling you this, but your question isn't very easy to answer, and you will need to [edit] it to bring it up to standard. For one thing, you need to provide not all your code, but just a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); for another thing, you need to describe precisely what you are trying and _what is going wrong when you do that_.

Comment: Without that, you are asking people to review  your entire code, figure out what it is trying to do and how it might be going wrong, and recommend changes.That would be a full code review, and is not really on topic for this site; take a look at the [guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

Web server logs can't be accessed that way, nor should you want them to be.  Also, if your server is only running on localhost, then only the computer running the web server can access the web server.

It's difficult to say what you're trying to achieve here, and what your network is like.  I'm assuming you've a web server running on one machine, and you're trying to access it from another.  You'll need to provide more information.